# Fetch all data in array

Tags: php

I am trying to add the direction, left and right member to direct but the problem now here is that I am only able to fetch one data (left_mem) instead of both left_mem and right_mem.

```
$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("select * from users where enroller_id='".$enroller_id_n."' ");
$direct = array();
if($query){
    while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
        $enroller_id3 = $row['enroller_id'];
        $direct[] = $row['direction'];
    }
}
if ($direct == "left_mem")
{
  echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "fail";
 }
```

This is my database

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `enroller_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `enrolled_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `direction` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'avail'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `user_email`, `user_pass`, `enroller_id`, `enrolled_id`, `direction`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$direct` on each pass, so it can never be both "left_mem" and "right_mem".

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're sharing the correct code? It doesn't look like it could compile.

Comment: Also, how can a string with value "A" also have value "B" at the same time?

Comment: And what is `$direct` doing just hanging there on line 2

Comment: @aynber, yea, so how can I pass both left_mem and right to the variable

Comment: The main problem i that code does not compile. Fix that first then worry about the code being correct

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: `direct == "left_mem" && direct == "right_mem" ` even if it had the `$` sign in front of the variables name **CANNOT EVER BE** I cannot be an Orange && an Apple. **Oh and its a array anyway.**

Comment: no, my question is just how I could pass left_mem and right_mem of the enroller_id into variables

Comment: This is turning into a real movable feast. PHP Variables start with a `$`

Comment: I really think you should pick another hobbie coding is not for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `in_array` to see if both values exist:

```
if (in_array('left_mem',$direct) && in_array('right_mem',$direct)  )
```

Comment: how to store the values into $direct?

Comment: The method you're using, `$direct[] = $row['direction'];`, will work just fine